# matlab lego NXT - check when tacholimit reached

Tags: matlab, lego-mindstorms

Basically I'm trying to find a way to check when tacholimit has been reached. I could use the `Waitfor` but I want to get data from sensors while the motor is rotating.

I am using the MATLAB library for Lego developed by the [RWTH Aachen](http://www.mindstorms.rwth-aachen.de).

```
motor.SendToNXT();
motor.WaitFor();
Time(1)=0.0;

  tic;
  i=1; 
  while % here is what I need a way to check if tacholimit is reached
   % get values from sensor end
   Time(i)=toc; 
end
```